# How to calculate offset for the Stake Program in getProgramAccounts

Tags: rpc, getprogramaccounts, memcmp, offset

I'd like to come up with the right `memcmp`->`offset` filter to be used with `getProgramAccounts`. I am trying to query stake accounts associated with a `voter`. I spent a bunch of time looking up the structs but cannot wrap my head around how the base58 data is structured. Thanks in advance

Comment: So some reverse engineering - found the offset is 124, but still would like to know where in the code I could see the structure of the logic that packs these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native stake program's top-level state type is declared [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/6928b2a5af45bf6985b90ff116cf47f917ac1c9c/sdk/program/src/stake/state.rs#L21-L26).  It's serialized using [`bincode`](https://crates.io/crates/bincode)

Comment: Will mark this as the answer, but I found an extremely helpful doc here too. https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html

Answer (score 1):

The Anchor book has this great space reference, which gives a good guide on how much space each data type takes up:

https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/space.html

So once you know the types in the struct, and what order they're in (which is the same order as they appear in code), then you can work out the proper offset.

Keep in mind also that Anchor account types have an 8-byte discriminator up front before any data fields.

Comment: the native stake program does not use anchor

Comment: Ah, ok. It wasn't clear to me from the OP that the native stake program was the particular program in question.